# Scene Builder: Change FXML location

Tags: gradle, javafx-8, scenebuilder

On the one hand *Scene Builder* expects FXML files in the same folder as the Controller classes, so the FXML files end up in `src/main/java`.

On the other hand most Java projects put resources in the `src/main/resources`.

Now, using *Gradle*, you must tweak the build script due to the facht *Gradle* does not pick up resources in the 'java' folder.

Is there a way to change the behavior of Scene Builder so he expects FXML files in different locations?

Comment: Disclaimer: I've never used `javafx`. Please show the code where you load the `fxml` file. I'm guessing you're doing something wierd where you are using `java.io.File` instead of `java.lang.ClassLoader`. Assuming `fxml` is loaded at runtime (not build time), `javafx` should not know anything about the location of your java sources.

Comment: @LanceJava The question is about Scene Builder: the point is that it can only read contextual information (such as `@FXML-annotated fields and handler methods) from a controller source file if that source file is in the same folder as the FXML file. It has nothing to do with what happens at runtime at all.

Comment: AFAIK there is currently no way to do this. There are a number of feature requests for this: https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/99/search-for-fxml-controller-class-under, https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/112/scenebuilder-cant-work-with-a-controller, and https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/137/option-to-find-controller-classes-in.

Comment: Ok, finally googled what scenebuilder is and it's a build-time wysiwig editor thing. So yeah, that's a bit broken and should allow xml files to live in the resource folders rather than assuming they live next to the java files (not sure if I've mentioned but that's silly!). So yeah, you'll have to tweak(hack?) gradle to allow that silly setup... which is fine... because gradle is highly configurable

Comment: @James_D Scene Builder should be OSS - wouldn't be there a way to implement this feature by the community?

Comment: It is... you can go to https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder, fork the project, add the feature and create a pull request...

Comment: @James_D Apparently there are already pull-request regarding this, maybe Gulon should check them ... Am I the only person who has this problem or why was there no chance so far? JavaFX 8 is now almost two years in production ...

Comment: No idea. Obviously you are not the *only* person, since there are three feature requests... But I don't think too many people are using gradle or Maven to build JavaFX projects. It's usually more convenient to use something like e(fx)clipse or native NetBeans wizards, which will manage the FX deployment for you. Simply including the resource next to the controller source works in those cases. (I typically use Maven for dependency management, but not for builds, in JavaFX projects.)

Comment: FWIW the FXML file and controller are really quite tightly coupled, so I kind of like having them in the same physical source directory anyway....

Comment: Personally, I don't want to move my fxml files to a resources directory. I want them in the same directory as the controller classes that use them, since I often go back and forth between the fxml files and the controllers. There needs to be a way for Gradle to easily allow this.